# Why am I getting "Class 'sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row' is not mapped" when trying to delete a record?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've just moved from SQLAlchemy 1.3 to 1.4 and am trying out the new 2.0 syntax. Given the following table:

```
class Player(Base):

    __table_args__ = {"schema": "test"}
    __tablename__ = "player"

    id_ = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name_ = sa.Column(sa.String(100))
```

I add some records:

```
dal.session.add_all([Player(1, "t1"), Player(2, "t2"), Player(3, "t3")])
```

I can delete records using 1.x:

```
del_records = session.query(Player).filter(Player.id_ <= 10)
for d in del_records:
    session.delete(d)
```

However, when I switch to 2.0:

```
del_records = session.execute(sa.select(Player).where(Player.id_ <= 10))
for d in del_records:
    session.delete(d)
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: UnmappedInstanceError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: <module>)
Class 'sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row' is not mapped

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  File "/Users/philipjoss/Documents/GitHub/polgara/sandpit.py", line 61, in <module> (Current frame)
    dal.session.delete(d)
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Got this `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row' is not mapped` error as well.

What finally resolved it for me was to move from using

```
db.session.delete(user)
db.session.commit()
```

to

```
db.session.execute(db.delete(User).filter_by(user_id=user_id))
db.session.commit()
```